# Migrate form Physical to Virtualized Infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, google-cloud-storage, openstack, opennebula

I am new to cloud computing and still trying to learn a lot of things.

Say I have my data center running(Non Virtualized) some Ad Server. One day I realized that the load has increased to an  unmanageable extent and since I have limited hardware, I can't do anything to handle an abrupt and very large load(out of my data center capability). For such situations, Cloud Computing comes to rescue. We can allocate and deallocate resources dynamically.

Now, Since I am not using any cloud platform like openstack, opennebula. I will not be able to migrate my load to A third party service provider say AWS.

**My question is** that how we should handle situations like these when we are not running any virtualized data center but still want to be elastic and scale to a third party provider and pay them accordingly.

**I know the question is not formulated properly but experts will understand my problem easily**.

I am a student and just want learn this. Not asking for any assignment/homework help.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach is to use weighted DNS Records. For example, you can set www.yoursite.com to resolve to onpremise.yoursite.com 42% of the time and to aws.yoursite.com otherwise.

But, as you know, this is a broad problem and good answers are context specific.